# Transfer input from HTML InputBox to JavaScript and run a Selenium code using that input

Tags: javascript, selenium

I built a Selenium program to scrape different data from a specific website.
Next thing is I made an input box in an HTML page, I want to paste a product address into the input box and send that input over to my JavaScript Selenium program to be executed via node.js

Then I want the output data to be transferred back to the HTML website so I can display it

How do I do that? What do I need to learn / use in order to execute?

- I tried Browserify and WebPacks with no luck..
  TIA!